# Getting the below exception on using Date.parse function in Groovy java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.ui.Console

Tags: java, groovy

Up on using the below code i am getting the following Exception...

```
use(TimeCategory) {
def dt1=Date.parse("dd-mm-yyyy", a) + b.year;
def dt2=Date.parse("dd-mm-yyyy", c);
if (dt1>dt2) .....else ..}

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.ui.Console
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:179)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:151)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:104)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:136)
```

Can you please let me know the reason for it ..thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
def dt1= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy").parse(a) + b.year;
def dt2=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy").parse(c)
```

Changing the above code resolved the issue